# How to Batch Apply Multiple Commands? FFmpeg

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch

I have three commands that I've got to work individually for a set of videos, but cannot get them to apply together. I need to apply all three of these things to every video.

**1) add audio, 2) speed up entire video, 3) apply text overlay**

I've tried adding the different lines together using '&&' or separating by commas but can't get it to work. What is the right way to batch apply multiple edits to several videos?
I'm also unsure how to apply the first line to all videos.
Note: I'm on Windows and using the command line.

```
ffmpeg -i audiofile.mp3 -i videofile.mp4 -filter_complex amix=normalize=0:weights="0.02 1" videofileoutput.mp4

for %f in ("folder\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.5" -af atempo=1.5 "folder\%~nf_suffix.mp4"

for %f in ("folder\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vf drawtext="fontfile=arial.ttf: text='@texthere': fontcolor=white@1: fontsize=50: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" "folder\%~nf_suffix.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

This would mix all videos in folder with the same audifile Audiofile.mp3, speed up video and audio by 50% and apply a text on the screen:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b folder\*.mp4') do ffmpeg -i "%f" -i "Audiofile.mp3" -filter_complex "[0][1]amix=normalize=0:weights='0.02 1'[audio],[0]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.5[video];[audio]atempo=1.5[audio];[video][audio]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[final];[final]drawtext=text='@texthere':font=arial:fontcolor=white@1:fontsize=50:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2[final]" -map [final] "%~nf_suffix%~xf"
```

To apply on a batch script with selecting a random mp3 file:

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "VideoFolder=C:\Users\Ricardo\Videos"
set "AudioFolder=C:\Users\Ricardo\Music\The Official UK Top 100 (09-11-2023)"

IF NOT EXIST "%VideoFolder%\" exit
IF NOT EXIST "%AudioFolder%\" exit

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%AudioFolder%\*.mp3"') do (
                                                             set /a MaxAudioFiles+=1
                                                             set "Audio[!MaxAudioFiles!]=%%a"
                                                            )

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%VideoFolder%\*.mp4" "%VideoFolder%\*.mkv"') do Call :Mix "%%~a"
exit

:Mix
set /a RandomFile=%random% * (%MaxAudioFiles% - 1 + 1) /32768 + 1 
ffmpeg -i "%VideoFolder%\%~1" -i "%AudioFolder%\!Audio[%RandomFile%]!" -map_metadata -1 -filter_complex ""[0][1]amix=normalize=0:weights='0.02 1'[audio],[0]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.5[video];[audio]atempo=1.5[audio];[video][audio]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[final];[final]drawtext=text='@texthere':font=arial:fontcolor=white@1:fontsize=50:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2[final]" -y "%VideoFolder%\%~n1_mod%~x1"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work when I removed the /f "delims =" and added parentheses in the folder path similar to how I have the 3 individual codes above. I see you also commented on my post on selecting an mp3 at random, do you know how I could implement that into this same line instead of the single "audiofile.mp3"?

Comment: Ok, I added it to the answer...